# 301 redirect a subdomain and all its variants (https, www, etc)

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, https, subdomain

I want to redirect 301 from `abc.example.com` to `example.com/abc.html` page.

I would like to include all variants of the subdomain in the redirect, like

- `abc.example.com`
- `www.abc.example.com`
- `https://www.abc.example.com`

**Update:**

It is a shared hosting and Apache server.
And It is the real scenario, which i need to move.

`https://www.quickbooksrecovery.example.com/` page to this page `https://www.example.com/quickbooks-file-recovery.html`

Added as Add-on domain and SSL certificate installed by the hosting company.

Comment: What server and hosting do you have?   The solution is going to be different on shared hosting vs your own server.  The solution is also going to vary based on what web server you use (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc)

Comment: Do you have an existing security certificate that covers `abc.example.com` and `www.abc.example.com`?   If not, do you purchase your certificates or use LetsEncrypt?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the details I requested so that the question can be re-opened and answered.

Comment: It is a shared hosting and Apache server.

Comment: Can you also add details about what you're doing for your SSL certificates please?

Comment: Within your shared hosting, how is the subdomain set up? Is it set up as an add-on domain? Does the document route to the same directory as your main site? Or does it point to some other directory?

Comment: To emphasise/build on Stephen's comment above... where does the subdomain point on the filesystem? Is this the same directory as the main domain? Or a subdirectory of the main domain? Or somewhere else entirely? Do you have an existing `.htaccess` file for the subdomain and/or main domain (relevant if the subdomain points to a subdirectory off the main domain)?