# 301 Redirect subdomain to web page

Tags: 301-redirect

I want to redirect sub domain to web page. Below is the URL.

`https://www.quickbooksrecovery.example.com/` page to this page `https://www.example.com/quickbooks-file-recovery.html`

It is a shared hosting and Apache server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [301 redirect a subdomain and all its variants (https, www, etc)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136864/301-redirect-a-subdomain-and-all-its-variants-https-www-etc)

Comment: no, I need a code for htacces.

Comment: Instead of posting duplicate questions or editing them to add updates that you're still waiting for an answer (which is not condoned here), please address the comments being asked in your original question. Otherwise, perhaps this might be helpful to you since it contains most of the common redirects using an Apache .htaccess:  [What are the most commonly used and basic Apache htaccess redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-and-basic-apache-htaccess-redirects)